# Sprite node suddenly not found Godot

Tags: godot, gdscript

I added my player as a singleton and now Godot cannot find its sprite node. The game crashes when I try to move and gives me a "get_node: Node not found: Sprite." error. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: The singleton is a kinematicbody2D and I'm trying to access its child node, Sprite(animated_sprite), which whenever I type in kinematicbody2D's script something along the lines "$Sprite" it says that Sprite can't be found

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of your script and a screenshot of your hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

If by "singleton" you mean [AutoLoad](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/singletons_autoload.html), please pay attention that this concept was introduced to Godot as a workaround for storing scene-independent or inter-scene information. As documentation says:

> When autoloading a script, a Node will be created and the script will be attached to it. This node will be added to the root viewport before any other scenes are loaded.

As far as I understood from your question, the `Sprite` node is a child of a node that had a script attached to it with a line of code, similar to

```
self.get_node("Sprite")...
```

But when you `AutoLoad`ed this script, you actually introduced a new node as a child of a root viewport, and this node does not inherit the tree structure of the "original" node that had `Sprite` child. It has only the same script attached as the original node. Also referring by `AutoLoad` name will refer to this new object (without `Sprite` child) rather than your original one.

I think what you wanted to do is to provide an inter-scene way to refer to that particular node (that has its `Sprite` child). I would recommend to look into [Godot's Groups](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/getting_started/step_by_step/scripting_continued.html#groups) to do that in a clean way. Put your node to a specific group and then request it from that group:

```
theNode.add_to_group("MyPublicNodes")

# Get that node somewhere and get its `Sprite` child
get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("MyPublicNodes")[0].get_node("Sprite")
```